# set an active menu item based on current URL with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight the current link in my nav menu based on the current active URL.

I have found many solutions if my nav menu was pure CSS, but my menu is image-based therefore the active class is different for every link, and that is where I am stuck.

Can anyone suggest something that I can use? I am quite new to jQuery but find it exceptionally useful and one of the best languages I have learned.

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="navmenu">
        <li><a class="products" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="services" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="about-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="contact-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="directory" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="blog" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each `a` tag has a pre-loaded CSS background image, and every class has a hover function.

Comment: jQuery is not a language, a JavaScript library.

Comment: How the URLs look like? All you have to do is to "connect" css classes with urls. Do you use ajax to download the page or full page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get the part of the url after the #:

```
window.location.hash
```

Then use jQuery again to highlight the relevant element:

```
var linkClass = window.location.hash;
$("."+linkClass).prop("class",linkClass+" highlight");
```

This is just one way to do it (may not be the most elegant). In this case your css would be something like this:

```
.pageOne {

}  
.pageOne.highlight {

}
```

and your HTML like this:

```
<a href="pageOne.html#pageOne">Page One</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why a CSS based approach won't work for you. There are two main approaches in my mind:

First, place class on a parent element, fex:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="navmenu">
        <li><a class="products" href="#"></a></li>
        <!-- This is the current page -->
        <li class="current"><a class="services" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="about-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="contact-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="directory" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="blog" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can then use the following CSS rules:

```
.current .products { /* ... */ }
.current .services { /* ... */ }
.current .about.us { /* ... */ }
.current .contact-us { /* .... */ }
.current .directory { /* ... */ }
.current .bloc { /* ... */ }
```

This solution allows you to have different styles for each entry, which is good if you need to change the image fex.

The other solution is easier if you need to have the same styles for all entries and is based on having multiple classes on an element:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="navmenu">
        <li><a class="products" href="#"></a></li>
        <!-- This is the current page -->
        <li><a class="services current" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="about-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="contact-us" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="directory" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="blog" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS will then be:

```
.current { /* ... */ }
```